# Looking for better-than-O(n^2) algorithm for “factorial base” representation of permutation

Tags: algorithm

I'm looking for an efficient algorithm to compute a [factorial-base representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system) (aka "Cantor expansion") of a given a `n`-permutation.

By "efficient" I mean one with better than `O(n2)` running time.

---

(BTW, I realize that there are multiple natural ways to map permutations to factorial-base representations, differing only in the conventions adopted, and that the algorithm I'm looking for depends to some extent on the particular conventions chosen.  At the moment I have no strong preference on the matter, although this rests mostly on the unproven assumption that any algorithm written for one set of conventions will be easily converted to one supporting a different set of conventions, without any adverse effect on the running time.)

FWIW, an example of an `O(n2)`-time algorithm to compute a factorial base representation of a permutation of the list `(0, 1, ..., n-1)` would be one that computes the `i`-th digit, `d_i`, of such a representation as the number of inversions (in the given permutation) between the `i`-th element and some *subsequent* element in the permutation.

Or, in pseudocode, (assuming 0-based arrays):

```
function FACTORIAL_REPRESENTATION(p):
    n <- length(p)
    d <- zeros(n - 1)
    for i <- 0 to n - 3:
        for j <- i + 1 to n - 2:
            if p[i] > p[j]:
                d[i] <- d[i] + 1
    return d
```

For example, given the permutation [2, 3, 1, 0] of [0, 1, 2, 3], the function above should return the array [2, 2, 1], corresponding to the inversions

- 2 : [***2***, 3, ***1***, 0], [***2***, 3, 1, ***0***]
- 2 : [2, ***3***, ***1***, 0], [2, ***3***, 1, ***0***]
- 1 : [2, 3, ***1***, ***0***]

Since counting inversions seems to me akin to sorting, and since sorting can be done in `O(nlogn)`, I suppose that there may be at least an `O(nlogn)` algorithm for doing this, but I have not been able to come up with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop

```
    for j <- i + 1 to n - 2:
        if p[i] > p[j]:
            d[i] <- d[i] + 1
```

is simply a rank query; you want to know how many elements of `p` after the `i`th are less than `p[i]`.  You can modify a balanced binary search tree to report the rank of an element in logarithmic time in addition to its usual operations.  You can initialise such a tree to contain all of `p`.  Then you are setting `d[i]` to `rank(p[i])` and deleting `p[i]`.   (You could also run your loop backward and do insertions instead of deletions.)

Comment: I'm having a hard time translating your answer into code.  For one thing, at least in the example I showed, where one is working with permutations of the integers (0, ..., n-1), the ranks are the permuted elements themselves, so I don't see what the tree gives me...

Comment: The tree lets you run that loop in logarithmic time.  You need to augment the tree so that it can handle rank queries.  (Or you can use a specialised tree for doing rank queries on {0, ..., n-1}.)

Comment: Assuming you have a data structure that can answer rank queries under inserts and deletes, do you see how to solve your problem?